# IE 10 padding issue with sticky footer

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I want to page with no scroll and sticky footer .There is no problem with chrome and firefox. But IE 10 shows extra padding. Here is my [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jamoon/bawQv/).

```
<style>
.clearfix:after  {content: "."; display: block; 
                  clear: both; visibility: hidden;
                  line-height: 0; height: 0;}

.clearfix        {zoom: 1;}

#fixedmenu      {height:75px; background:#A2BBD5; 
                 font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                 font-size:12px;}

.kapsa           {min-height:574px; padding-bottom: 25px;
                  text-align:center;}

.w100            {width:100%;}

.maz             {margin:0 auto;width:1000px;}

.footer          {min-width:1000px; margin-top: -25px;
                  height: 25px; background:#EC2155;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.kapsa').height($(window).height() - 100);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');

});
</script>

<div id="fixedmenu" class="w100 clearfix"></div>

<div class="kapsa maz"></div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: We can't see your fiddle because you've added double quotes to the link. Further more you have to post here some code for us to see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference on IE to what I see on Safari or Chrome.

What you could try is putting !important behind your set padding and/or defining you padding even if it's just

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This should actually be a comment, not an answer. You can comment once you earn enough reputation, so you should work on that. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but I considered it a proposition to an answer

Comment: I understand, my bad. :-)